# How to transfer compound types with JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

If i have structs on the c++ side like (simplified):

```
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}
```

and

```
struct BSpline
{
    std::vector<Point> knot;
    std::vector<Point> cp;
}

struct Curve
{
    std::vector<Point> Points;
}
```

(and the structs have their corresponding java classes)

From the Java side, I want to use them like (not exactly):

```
public native BSpline approximate(Curve);
```

How can I transfer the data structure most effectively?

UPDATE:

Assuming I use:

```
public native double[] approximate(double[],int p,int n);
```

How can I handle the double[]-s from the c++ side?

Comment: If you allocate a direct ByteBuffer on the Java side, there are methods you can use to read and write an arbitrary sequence of primitive types from that, which could be matched by structure definitions on the native side.

Comment: Any example, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

The only types you can pass between Java and C through the JNI interface are listed there.  You can't pass C/C++ structures or classes.  You can pass java arrays, but you need to do the decomposition into your stl containers manually.

**UPDATE**:
javah should generate a header file that will give you the types.  That is for the above native function javah will gen something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_T_approximate
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject, jdoubleArray theArray, jint, jint);
```

You can then create a vector thusly:

```
jsize size = env->GetArrayLength( theArray);
std::vector<double> input( size );
env->GetDoubleArrayRegion( arr, 0, size, &input[0] );
```

The return value can be created similarly:

```
vector<double> returnArray;
...
jdoubleArray retVal = env->NewDoubleArray( returnArray.size() );
env->SetDoubleArrayRegion( retVal, 0, returnArray.size(), &returnArray[0] );
return retVal;
```

Unfortunately, Oracle's documentation for the JNI functions is a bit limited.  Have a look here for more information:
[jikesrvm.sourceforge.net/apidocs/latest/org/jikesrvm/jni/JNIFunctions.html](http://jikesrvm.sourceforge.net/apidocs/latest/org/jikesrvm/jni/JNIFunctions.html)